# I couldn't find the mistake that is in my discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot that is currently changing the channel names which is in the guild. But there is a problem when I run the program with node.js my function returns undefined values. But in function everything is true.

```
   function fetchdataFromApiUsd(moneykind){
    fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base="+moneykind)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) =>{
        const sonuc = data.rates
        console.log(sonuc.TRY);//The values come true.
        return sonuc.TRY;
       
    } )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
   }
```

But when I called like this

```
   client.on('message', msg => {
     if (msg.content === 'ping') {
      msg.reply('Pong!');
       }
     if(msg.content==='hiThere'){
       const currentusd=fetchdataFromApiUsd("USD");
       const currenteuro=fetchdataFromApiUsd("EUR");
      let myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get(msg.guild.id)
      let channel = myGuild.channels.cache.get('297798780592324610')
      let channel1 = myGuild.channels.cache.get('297798809533022208')
      channel.setName('1 Dolar = '+currentusd) //Returns undefined
      channel1.setName('1 Euro = '+currenteuro)//Returns undefined
     .catch()
     console.log(currentusd)  //Returns undefined
     console.log(currenteuro) //Returns undefined
  }
});
```

[image: Console screen]

Comment: Turn fetchdataFromApiUsd function into a Promise and await for it.

Comment: That is because your program is logging/changing the channel name before the api data is received, hence the undefined

Comment: @Jakye I already tried it but it's still turning undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was async variables.  I define the variables out of curly brackets. It's worked. Also, you should call those variables in the function to define again updating values.

```js
let usd,eur;
function ddd(){
    
    exchange("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD").then((data)=>{usd=data}).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
   exchange("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=EUR").then((data)=>{eur=data}).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
   console.log(usd,eur)

}

function exchange(url){
   
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const prop=data.rates.TRY;
 
        resolve(prop);
       
                    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})

}
```